# What citation / reference styles explicitly tell the reference's type?

Tags: citation-style

Is there a - or more properly are there (considering the excessive amount of syles existing) - reference/citation styles which have the following feature?

In the reference the type of the reference is explicitly mentioned, i.e. it is stated explicitly as a word in the reference.

To make this clear find some examples below:

1. a book

Authorlast, Authorfirst. (2015) *The meaning and importance of citations in science*. Publisher: Publishlocation. [BOOK]

2. or journal

Authorlast, Authorfirst; Coauthorlast, Coauthorfirst. (2015) *Suggestions for more traceable reference lists*. In Journal of Ergonomic Academia, 34(2), 23-34. [JOURNAL ARTICLE]

3. or book chapter

Authorlast, Authorfirst. (2015) *Title of book chapter*. In Editorlast, Editorfirst. Title of the book Publisher: Publishlocation. [BOOK CHAPTER]

4. or webpage

Stack Exchange (2015) *Academia Stack Exchange:*. Retrieved February 19, 2015, FROM https://academia.stackexchange.com [WEBPAGE]

It would be great to not reinvent the wheel here and invent yet another citation style, which motivates my question. I am sure that it is only in this current phase of multi-media (types) in which new varieties of digital sources of knowledge can found (video, blog entry, manuals, government documents etc.)

Since my hope is that the idea of having citations an reference is the ability to reuse and make traceable knowledge and concepts developed elsewhere the type of the reference would be amply helpful in finding the sources.

Comment: What sort of publication are you targeting?  Most places that you write a paper for will have a required citation style...

Comment: This is quite off-topic here. You can do whatever you wish basically, you just write it there. If you ask how to do it in LaTeX (BibTeX or biblatex), then the right place is [TeX.SX](http://tex.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @yo' He is asking whether such style exists or not. He is not asking whether it is better or not to cite like that. He is not even asking about a technical feature. I think his question is on-topic for this site. Moreover, it will not be cross posting a question, if he post a question on TeX.SE asking about some technical features of his question there.

Comment: @EnthusiasticStudent Such style exist, the OP has just created it. That's the problem: there's no "standard of standards" for citation styles, so whatever you create and satisfies the minimal criteria for valid citations is fine. I've made an answer in this manner.

Answer (score 1):

Well, as you see, such style exists, at least in your question. Remember that while references have to satisfy some minimal criteria, there is not much more rules and the styles vary a lot. So certainly, if you take any widely used style and you add `(book)`, `(journal article)`, `(webpage)` or whatever at the end of each citation, you create a new bibliography style that complies with the rules. If you really need to distinguish it like this, then what you shown looks usable, just please for Gutenberg's sake, don't make it all-caps.